# Gráficos React-chartjs-2 não carregam na tela

Tags: javascript, html, react

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Bar} from 'react-chartjs-2';
import $ from 'jquery';

//NÚMERO DE VIAGENS POR MUNICIPIO

class GeraGrafico extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            listaMedia:[], 
            listaMunicipio:[]
        }
    }
    
    componentWillMount(){
        console.log("MOUNT");
  $.ajax({
            url:"http://localhost:10774/sbrp-service/rest/grafico/viagens_municipio",
   dataType: 'json',
   success:function(resposta){
                console.log(resposta);
                var i;
    for (i = 0; i < resposta.length; i++) { 
      this.state.listaMedia.push(resposta[i].media);
      this.state.listaMunicipio.push(resposta[i].municipio);
    }
   }.bind(this)
   }
  );
 }
    
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Bar    
                    data={{
                        labels: this.state.listaMunicipio,
                        datasets: [
                        {
                            data: this.state.listaMedia,
                            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'
                        }]
                    }}
                    options={{
                        legend:{
                            display: false
                        }
                    }}
                    
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default class GraficoViagensMunicipio extends Component {
 render() {  
  return (
   <div>
    <div className="box box-primary">
     <div id="ViagemMunicipio" className="box-body">
      <GeraGrafico/>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  );
 }
}
```

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação usando React, na qual faço uma uma busca em um banco de dados e apresento graficamente os dados na tela da minha aplicação. Porém, o gráfico aparece vazio mesmo com os dados sendo carregados pelo back-end (consigo verificar isso com consolo.log()).

Após mudar as dimensões da página da aplicação (por exemplo, inspecionando o elemento) os dados são apresentados no gráfico.

Já passaram por isso? Sabem como posso resolver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu código tem alguns pontos de melhoria, mas acredito que o seu problema esteja se dando por duas coisas: Pelo fato de você estar fazendo a requisição antes do componente montar e pelo fato de você estar modificando o estado diretamente (dica: nunca faça isso. Leia sobre [aqui](https://daveceddia.com/why-not-modify-react-state-directly/)).

Primeiramente: o método `componentWillMount()` já está sendo marcado como [unsafe](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount) pelo pessoal do FB. Então isso por si só já deveria ser motivo suficiente pra mudar. Mas, mesmo assim, no link você lê que setar o estado dentro dele não provoca o *re-render*, então você não vai atingir o objetivo que você deseja de qualquer forma. Para chegar lá, use o [`componentDidMount()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount). Dentro dele, caso você altere o estado, o *re-render* será provocado e você, eventualmente, vai chegar no seu objetivo.

O outro ponto, como disse acima, é modificar o estado diretamente. Para mudá-lo, sempre (e eu digo *sempre*) use o [`setState()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate). Dessa forma, você pode substituir o seu `componentWillMount()` por

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log("MOUNT");
    $.ajax({
        url:"http://localhost:10774/sbrp-service/rest/grafico/viagens_municipio",
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(resposta) {
            console.log(resposta);

            const novaListaMedia = [];
            const novaListaMunicipio = [];

            for (let i = 0; i < resposta.length; i++) { 
                novaListaMedia.push(resposta[i].media);
                novaListaMunicipio.push(resposta[i].municipio);
            }

            this.setState({
                listaMedia: novaListaMedia,
                listaMunicipio: novaListaMunicipio
            });
        }
    }.bind(this));
};
```

Ainda, recomendo o uso de uma biblioteca mais moderna e enxuta para trabalhar com requisições assíncronas, como a [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios). Como você está usando React, você pode usar alguns conceitos mais modernos do JavaScript, e essa biblioteca usa vários! =)

Comment: Deu certo Caio! Comecei a mexer com o React a pouco tempo, então não tenho muita prática ainda. Mas sua resposta e as dicas me ajudaram bastante aqui. Muito obrigado!

Comment: @JoãoMarcosSoares todo mundo tem que começar por algum lugar ;)

Answer (score 1):

É possível que seus dados não estejam no formato adequado esperado pelo react-chartjs-2, o que causaria que o componente fosse carregado, no entanto sem exibir qualquer tipo de dado.
Sugiro que publique algum trecho de código para que eu possa tentar ajudar.

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção Pedro. Publiquei o código do meu componente junto à pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

O erro pode estar no ciclo de vida do seu componente e dos seus dados. Nesse caso os dados chegam após a renderização do seu componente, então o componente é renderizado vazio (sem dados).